# InputConnection commitText() doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, android

What could be a reason that commitText("something", 0) doesnt put out the text in the editbox? I am calling the function from an inner class, where the outer class is a InputMethodService.

Thanks for any tips/help.

Comment: Is the InputConnection valid?  Or is it possible it was broken (you should never save inputConnection between calls from the other app)?  commitText should generally make the text visible, unless they're doing something odd on the client side (like limiting the size of the input, or using filters to disable some characters).

Comment: i checked and the inputconnection is fine i think because commitext returns true. Isuch an annoying problem... thanks forvthe suggestion though

Comment: did you check current `EditorInfo` when calling `commitText()`? the easiest way is to use `getCurrentInputEditorInfo().dump()` method with `LogPrinter`

Comment: No I didnt yet. Will try it out now thanks!

Comment: So I just did `getCurrentInputEditorInfo().dump(new LogPrinter(Log.INFO, "test"), "DEBUG");` but don't get any response in the logcat somehow @pskink

Comment: try `Log.DEBUG` instead of `Log.INFO` and use `" >>>  "` instead of `"DEBUG"`

Comment: Still nothing :/ Thanks anyway!

Comment: do you have any filters in logcat window? just run `adb logcat` from the terminal window and you will see all messages

Comment: no I dont have any filters. the command cant be found also. hmm I think I will approach my original problem differently. dont wanna put more time into that. Thanks pskink for your help!

Comment: ok so simply create your own custom `Printer` - all you have to do is to implement one `println(String x)` method

Comment: Can I actually PM you about my actual problem. It seems to me there should be an easy soultion and I am just thinking to complicated or should I make a new post? @pskink

Comment: just call `EditorInfo#dump()` method in two cases: when `commitText` works and when it doesn't and compare the dumps

Comment: Ok I got it, not sure what this tells me though:
'I/test: >>>inputType=0x0 imeOptions=0x0 privateImeOptions=null
    >>>actionLabel=null actionId=0
    >>>initialSelStart=-1 initialSelEnd=-1 initialCapsMode=0x0
    >>>hintText=null label=null
    >>>packageName=io.anyline.examples fieldId=-1 fieldName=null
    >>>extras=null
    >>>hintLocales=null'

Comment: and whats the dump when `commitText` works? i believe `inputType` != 0 also `fieldName` would be != null

Comment: fieldName ist null but you are right that inputType isn't 0:

`I/test: >>>inputType=0x2c041 imeOptions=0x44000006 privateImeOptions=null
    >>>actionLabel=null actionId=0
    >>>initialSelStart=0 initialSelEnd=0 initialCapsMode=0x2000
    >>>hintText=Nachricht schreiben label=null
    >>>packageName=com.android.mms fieldId=2131427502 fieldName=null
    >>>extras=null
    >>>hintLocales=null`

Comment: @pskink so it is a problem with the Editor it seems. I guess the proper Editor is not set. What do you think?

Comment: yes, `EditorInfo` is broken so there is no field which could accept your text send by `commitText` method - i believe those two are most important `inputType=0x2c041` and  `imeOptions=0x44000006` but in the second case they are both 0

Comment: ok any idea how to fix that? @pskink or at least how I should proceed? or is there maybe a way to set the aprropriate Editor?

Comment: you cannot have the second activity as it breaks everything - if you need a complex keyboard go `Fullscreen` mode

Comment: I see. Actually is there a way to "resfresh the keyboard". I mean I could put the result I need in a globale variable and then commitText again. But I could just commitText with the new variable on the next run right? That would kind of solve my problem. @pskink

Comment: why would you want such workarounds? what do you need the other `Activity` for? why cannot you do all the work in a custom `InputMethodService`?

Comment: Basically it is just a Keyboard that I amimplementing for someone, but I got the activity sdk (for scanning), so the activity does its thing and returns the value @pskink

Comment: ok so read `InputMethodService#on*` methods documentation and probably you will find one when `EditorInfo` is valid again after finishing the second `Activity` (`onStartInputView` maybe?)

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for all the help! Can you help me further if I stumble upon any problems?

Comment: the method worked for me is InputMethodService#onStartInput().